# Using methods in thread pool

Tags: c#, threadpool

I want to run a method in a thread pool. While build the following code it gives an error

> No overload for 'method' matches delegate 'System.Threading.WaitCallback'.

I know where the error happens, but I don't know why:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
namespace Thread_Pool
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(PrintNumbers));
           // PrintNumbers();
        }
        static void PrintNumbers()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the above code is rewritten as the following, it works fine.

```
static void PrintNumbers(object Stateinfo)
```

Why does this happen? Instead of using object may I use another type (like `int`, `float`)?

Answer (score 1):

> i know where the error happens, but i dont know why? when the above
>   code is rewritten as following, it works fine

You have to follow the singnature that is required by `WaitCallback`, as you can see the delegate definition of [WaitCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is why `PrintNumbers` need to have a parameter of type `object`.

```
public delegate void WaitCallback(
    Object state
)
```

> why this happens? and instead of using object may i use another type
>   (like int, float)? is it possible?

Yes, you can use `Convert.ToDouble(obj);`

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Threading.WaitCallback);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

`WaitCallback` delegate *wants* an `Object` argument:

```
  [ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
  public delegate void WaitCallback(Object state)
```

So you should *provide* it even if you're not going to use it:

```
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(PrintNumbers));
  }

  static void PrintNumbers(Object state) { // <- "Object state" is required here
    ...
  }
```

If you want to leave *PrintNumbers* intact you can use *lambda*:

```
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
      (Object state) => { // <- You have to use "Object state"
        PrintNumbers();  
      } 
    );
  }

  static void PrintNumbers() { 
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Number and types of arguments must match when creating delegates.

In current versions of C# it is easier to use lambda expressions than explicitly typed delegates. It makes converting types easier and allows to pass strongly typed parameters

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( unused => PrintNumbers()));

int intBalue = 1;
double doubleValue = 2;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( unused => Method(intValue, doubleValue) );
```

or you still can pass value as usual:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( state => MethodTakinObject(state));
```

Answer (score 0):

WaitCallback is a delegate accepting the parameter object. In order to use the delegate your method has to match the delegate signature like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( new WaitCallback( PrintNumbers ) );

}


static void PrintNumbers(object a)
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
     {
        Console.WriteLine( i );
        Thread.Sleep( 3000 );
     }
}
```

or you could simply use a lambda expression

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( a => { PrintNumbers(); } );
```

Functionality wise both approaches are the same. The "state" argument is only required when you intend to pass in values into your method.